# Search if a date in a range of date is include in a range of date

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, where-clause

I use oracle

```
create table "prba" 
( 
  "prba_id" number(18,0) not null, 
  "start_date" date not null, 
  "end_date" date 
);
```

I have some data

```
prba_id | start_date | end_date

    900 | 2020-01-20 | 2020-07-01
    901 | 2017-01-20 | 2018-08-03
    911 | 2020-09-01 |
```

I have a range of date 2020-01-20 (exclude)  to 2021-01-20 (include)

I search to get row where a date of this range in include in the start_date / end_date of prba... if end_date is null, we can suppose end_date is start_date + 1 year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want rows whose date range *overlaps* the parameter range. If so, consider:

```
select t.*
from prba
where coalesce(end_date, add_months(start_date, 12)) > date '2020-01-20'
  and start_date <= date '2020-07-20'
```